# Hard Time Writing NewLine in a .TXT File

Tags: vb.net

Basically what I am doing is writing a program that pulls a quote from a website and writes it to a .txt file. It works fine except that I have no idea who to add NewLine into the .txt file. I will just show you the code.

```
If Not div Is Nothing Then
        Dim blank As String = Environment.NewLine
        Dim finish As String = (div.InnerText.Trim())
        TextBox2.Text = Chr(34) & finish & Chr(34)
        Dim fileName As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Horoscope", "Monthly.txt")
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(fileName, Chr(34) & finish & Chr(34), True)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("userprofile"), "Documents\Horoscope\Monthly.txt"), blank, True)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("userprofile"), "Documents\Horoscope\Monthly.txt"), blank, True)
    End If
```

Now that works fine for the first pair of quotes, but anything after it does not indent due to another section of code that I have that deletes duplicates.

```
Dim lines As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Horoscope", "Monthly.txt"))
    lines = lines.Distinct().ToArray()
    IO.File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Horoscope", "Monthly.txt"), lines)
```

Is there another way that I can get the same affect of having a gap inbetween my quotes in a text file?

Comment: You want blank lines between each non-blank line after deleting the duplicates?

Comment: Correct! Kinda like hitting Enter twice in Microsoft Word. Should I add that same line of code, after the duplicate deletion code? Or is it something different that I am supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When removing the duplicates, you can drop the existing blank lines with `Where`, then add them back into the `lines` array using `SelectMany`:

```
lines = lines.
    Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).
    Distinct().
    SelectMany(Function(x) { x, String.Empty }).
    ToArray()
```

The `SelectMany` returns the line, plus a blank, for each line left after the `Distinct`.

You may also want to use `File.AppendAllLines` when adding new entries - seems a little cleaner:

```
File.AppendAllLines(fileName, { Chr(34) & finish & Chr(34), ""})
```

**EDIT**

This would fit in with your code something like this:

```
If Not div Is Nothing Then
    Dim finish As String = (div.InnerText.Trim())
    TextBox2.Text = Chr(34) & finish & Chr(34)
    Dim fileName As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Horoscope", "Monthly.txt")
    IO.File.AppendAllLines(fileName, { Chr(34) & finish & Chr(34), ""})
End If
'...
Dim lines As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Horoscope", "Monthly.txt"))
lines = lines.
    Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).
    Distinct().
    SelectMany(Function(x) { x, String.Empty }).
    ToArray()
IO.File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Horoscope", "Monthly.txt"), lines)
```

Comment: So I would get rid of the 2 lines with "blanks" in them and add this in underneath the code that deletes duplicates?

Comment: Awesome man, you solved my last bug in the program. I'm very new to VB so you helped a lot. Thanks for showing me that!